# Add a method dynamically to an object in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, dynamic, reflection

I want to do this JavaScript in Objective-C:

```
var obj = {};
obj.myFunc = function() { ... };
```

Is this possible? Or can methods only be added to a *class* in Objective-C and not an object? I.e. I found `class_addMethod`, but I'm wanting a way to have *different* implementations of the same selector on different instances of the same class.

Is this possible or am I SOL?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Objective-C, methods (even instance methods) are only defined on classes, not on individual objects.

You can create a new class at runtime using `objc_allocateClassPair` and add methods to that class.  You can change the class of an object at runtime using `object_setClass`.  You'll want to do some research on “isa-swizzling” if you decide to look into this.  It's particularly problematic if you want to use it on objects that you will also be using with KVO.

It will be much simpler if you can simply change your API to use blocks.  Example:

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

- (void)myMethodWithString:(NSString *)string;

typedef void (^MyMethodBlock)(NSString *string);

@property (nonatomic, copy) MyMethodBlock myMethodBlock;

@end

@implementation MyObject

@synthesize myMethodBlock = _myMethodBlock;

- (void)myMethodWithString:(NSString *)string {
    MyMethodBlock block = self.myMethodBlock;
    if (block) {
        block(string);
    }
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks this definitely helps. My thinking now is to create individual classes on the fly, setting the implementation of a selector on that class, then forwarding the invocation on the generic instance (of a class written to handle this) to that internal specific class instance.

Comment: My concern with that though is there doesn't appear to be any way to dynamically *destroy* or dealloc a class once created and registered.

Comment: You are correct.  You cannot remove a class once it is created.  An instance doesn't retain its class, so there is no way for the runtime to be sure it is safe to remove a class.

Answer (score 1):

Not directly possible. In JavaScript, objects inherit from other objects, whereas in Objective-C, inheritance is realized by classes.

I don't see why you would need this anyway, probably you have a design issue and you're presenting us an XY problem. However, here's a very ugly workaround solution I could imagine, just for educational funposes. Works only with methods taking exactly one argument.

```
id dispatch_helper(id obj, SEL sel, id arg)
{
    id (^blk)(id, SEL, id) = objc_getAssociatedObject(obj, sel);
    return blk(obj, sel, arg);
}

void object_addMethod(id obj, SEL sel, IMP imp)
{
    class_addMethod(object_getClass(obj), sel, dispatch_helper, "@@:@");
    objc_setAssociatedObject(obj, sel, ^(id o, SEL s, id a) {
        return IMP(o, s, a);
    }, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_COPY_NONATOMIC);
}
```